# Unable to run "Hello OSGi" program template in Eclipse Mars 4.5.1

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, osgi, eclipse-mars

I am new to OSGi, I am not able to run the "Hello OSGi Bundle" Template on Eclipse Mars(4.5.1), I am getting the below mentioned console messages.

My questions is - Do we need to install anything else except Eclipse Mars(4.5.1) to run the Hello OSGi Template? JDK I have is 1.7.0_80.

What I tried-

1. Search on internet for this problem - could not resolve in 2 days :(
2. In Run Configurations- click "Deselect All" Button then select my bundle then Click "Add Required bundles"(this action adds 2 more bundles)
3. Click - "Validate Bundles"- gave "No problems were detected" alert.
4. Click "Apply" button
5. Click "Run" button.
6. Resources that are added default by Eclipse Mars- [image]

**Console messages -**

```
Hello World!!
!SESSION 2016-02-05 15:27:02.454 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_80
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_IN
Command-line arguments:  -dev file:C:/Users/212553222/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/New_configuration/dev.properties -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -consoleLog -console

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-02-05 15:27:02.991
!MESSAGE Could not find bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.console
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not find bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.console
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.ConsoleManager.checkForConsoleBundle(ConsoleManager.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:231)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1488)
```

**UPDATE-**

Perhaps, the below worked for me in Eclipse Mars(reached there out of reading console error messages and luck) - [image]

OSGi Console Output-
[image]

**But still can not see the `osgi>` prompt in the command shell window(Windows 7), the shell just keeps on waiting. Why?** -[image]

Comment: All the necessary plugins are there, but the 'add required plugins' doesn't seem to do a very good job.

Comment: Thanks for the response! How do I proceed then? One more point is when I run on command shell(Windows 7) like- 
`C:\Desktop\eclipse\plugins>java -jar org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.101.v
20150820-1432.jar -console` , the `>OSGi` prompt is not coming rather the Command prompt keeps waiting...Also the console says that it can not find bundle - `org.eclipse.equinox.console` but the Equinox document says that it comes installed as a part of Eclipse Mars.

Comment: The best way to proceed would be to learn OSGi using [Bndtools](http://bndtools.org/).

Comment: Thanks! Will try that out, just curious why is the shell command `C:\Desktop\eclipse\plugins>java -jar org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.101.v 20150820-1432.jar -console` not giving the `>OSGi` prompt? That makes me think if I am missing something in the jars required..

Comment: Also right now I want only the Hello OSGi template to work and Bndtools seems a bit of an overhead just check Hello World on the OSGi console.

Comment: You might want to get started wth OSGi enRoute because it has a number of tutorials and is very nicely setup with bndtools. http://enroute.osgi.org